# Testing hammerjs events with angular2

Tags: unit-testing, angular, hammer.js

I'm building a testing suite and try to cover 100% of the code. Thing is, I have callback functions on panning. Does anyone how to correctly test hammerjs events with karma & jasmine on angular2 ?

HTML

```
<div (pan)="panning($event)" id="square">
```

TypeScript

```
public swiper($event) {
  let e = $event;
  let top = e.center.x - (e.target.clientHeight/2);
  let left = e.center.y - (e.target.clientWidth/2);
  e.target.style.transform = 'translate3d('+ top +'px, '+ left +'px, 0px)';
}
```

Thank you.

M

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use [this](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DebugElement-class.html):

```
it('should call panning on pan', (async() => {
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#square')).triggerEventHandler("pan", myNiceEvent)
    fixture.detectChanges()
    fixture.whenStable().then(testMyChanges)
}
```

I know it's been a long time, but I've struggled with that for Angular v5.2.0 myself.

Hoping this will help someone ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been looking for hours to find someway of simulating hammerjs gesture events in angular. this did the trick.

Comment: should this work with angular 6 and latest build of hammerjs 2.0.8 ? I am doing the same for press and pressup events but without success...

Comment: the API for DebugElement doesn't seem to have changed since then, so I assume it should work.
However, I don't have access to the source code for the working example above (company software), so I can't really test myself.
Does your code works when you trigger the events manually ?